# Visual studio angular template trying to add auto mapper

Tags: angular, .net-core, identity, angular-template

Im using the angular 8 template with identity that come with visual stuidio 19.

When i try to add automapper to the project and try to log in or requesta  page with autentication i get an error.

these are the packages i added: [image]

i register in startup like this :

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MappingProfile>(),
                               AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
```

I have my MappingProfile in another project in the same solution (currently empty)

```
 public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

this is the error i get :

[image]

Comment: See [this](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core). And also you need the AM version that IdentityServer uses, not the latest.

Comment: This really helped thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Lucians comment for anyone else looking the correct versions for the template are:

AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection = 7.0,
Automapper = 9.0